# Chatbox layout with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out a way to have my chatbox layout with a fixed header at the top and a fixed footer at the bottom all the while having the chatbox body scrollable and nests right up to both the fixed header and footer. I have tried a few different ways but still can't seem to get it just right and clean.

```css
.chat-head  {    
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
}
.chat-body  {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 93vh;
    margin: 25px 0;
    background:green;
}
.chat-foot {    
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col chat-head">
  One of three columns
</div>
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
<div class="col chat-body">chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>

</div>
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
<div class="col chat-foot">
  One of three columns
</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLysfspo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.container` with `position: relative` and some `padding`:

1. `padding-top` = `height` of fixed head;
2. `padding-bottom` = `height` of fixed footer;
3. Reset `margin` and `padding` for all DOM nodes.

Run the snippet below or take a look at this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0rmLLca/7/), is this the result you want?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chat-head {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}

.chat-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 80vh;
  background: green;
}

.chat-foot {
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col chat-head">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col chat-body">
    chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>


  </div>
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col chat-foot">
    One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but notice that you are trying to use Bootstrap to do this. When using Bootstrap try to write as less CSS as possible, otherwise it defeats the purpose of using the framework. Plus your custom CSS will eventually break features of the framework itself like the responsiveness of the components.

As an example I have rewritten your example using the [Card Component](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) and a [spacing utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) class. I used the card component with the `header`, `body` and `header` sections. To remove the padding in the y axis (top and bottom) of the `body` I used the spacing utility class `py-0`. Below is the final code

```css
.chat .card-header {
  background: red;
}

.chat .card-body {  
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
}

.chat .card-footer {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card chat">
  <div class="card-header">
    One of three columns
  </div>
  <div class="card-body py-0">
    chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>chat<br>

  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    One of three columns
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the whole container to be the full height of the page or container. Using vh and px seems to make that difficult. The chat body needs to be responsive while the header and footer are fixed.